# Would it be possible to make a capacitor from diamond

Tags: capacitance, dielectric

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_strength) the dielectric strength of diamond is $2000\frac{MV}{m}$, which is a lot higher than other materials, since it's density is $3500\frac{kg}{m^3}$ and it's dielectric constant is $5.7$, that would allow storing pulsed power at $29000\frac{J}{kg}$, which is very high.
But if for example I sandwich layers of aluminum and diamond, let's say $0.01mm$ thick, will it break at $20000V$?, or those figures aren't accurate for this use case?

Comment: IDK about the maximum voltage it can withstand, but you can use _any_ insulator to separate the plates of a capacitor.

Comment: But I mean, if it's true that diamond has that dielectric strength, then the capacitor could store a very high amount of energy since it is proportional to the square of the voltage, but maybe dielectric strength is measured in a different way, and I'm asking whether a real capacitor would withstand that voltage

Comment: clever idea, yes your diamond film theoretically would break down around 20kV $2GV/m = 2MV/mm = 2kV/\mu m$. The downside is that nobody likes to work with such high voltages in a practical environment, there are not many non-tube applications that would like to pulse at kV voltages.

Comment: Hey, some of us like MV pulses!

Comment: and some of us like tubes!